# Rows are not highlighted when I switch between pages

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF table with rows which are highlighted when they are clicked:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <ui:debug />

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Select" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="№" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="№" value="№" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + SessionsController.firstRow + 1}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>


                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>    

                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" >
                                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $("tr").not(':first').hover(
                            function () {
                                $(this).css("background","#707070");
                            }, 
                            function () {
                                $(this).css("background","");
                            }
                        );              

                            function highlight(param) {  
                                var row = jQuery(param).parent().parent().children();
                                row.toggleClass('highlited');
                            }        
                        </script>


                    </h:form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I select a row the row is highlighted:

[image]

But when I move to other page and I return back the selected rows are not highlighted. They are only checked:

[image]

Maybe I need other argument in this tag:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
```

Or I have to modify the JavaScript? How I can fix the problem?

PS. How I can modify the JavaScript to highlight every selected checkbox. Not just when It's called from the `onclick` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you change the page and go back, the rows are re-rendered, so all aplied css is lost.

you could consider using a component library, such as Primefaces, which handles that out of the box. Here you can see the demo:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: Is there any solution to my problem except using primefaces?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you would have to add a javascript that highlights all selected rows, and execute it after the the form is updated. but i strongly advice that you use a component library (primefaces, richfaces, icefaces..) because otherwise you have to handle tons of things that these libraries handle automatically like highlighting, pagination, filtering, ordering (and those only for datatables)